# AngularJS + Rails (How Not to Cache Templates?)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

Here is my project:

```
/app
  /assets
    /javascripts
      /templates              <- my angular templates
        home.html.erb
        my_template.html.erb
      my_app.js               <- my angular module
.
.
.
  /views
    /home
      index.html.erb          <- my rails view
```

I use [angular-rails-templates](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) to serve my angular templates through the asset pipeline.

Here is my_app.js :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router", "templates"])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    // I have two routes
    $stateProvider
      .state("/", {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "home.html"
      })
      .state("my_template", {
        url: "/my_template",
        templateUrl: "my_template.html"
      });
  });
```

Here is index.html.erb (rails view):

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <p>Hello...I'm inside a Rails view</p>
  <%= Time.new %>
  <div>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is home.html.erb (angular template):

```
<a href="#/my_template">
  Go To My Template
</a>
```

Here is my_template.html.erb (angular template):

```
<p>Hello...I'm inside an Angular template</p>
<%= Time.new %>
```

Here is the result when I navigate to "localhost:3000/#/my_template":

[image: Angular templates Caching]

I understand that this is the expected behaviour from Angular templates; however, I don't really understand where the separation of concerns happen between Angular and Rails.

I don't want to go full api with rails, and I don't want to go full SPA with Angular.

I'v been using Rails for years now, and I'm comfortable with many of its conventions, and the community-provided gems out there. (Devise, Pundit, etc.).

Having Angular cache every page with the pre-assumption that the back-end is a dumb api provider, is just too aggressive for me to make the switch.

The bottom line is, how can I selectively force Angular not to cache erb templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so much the expected behavior of Angular templates as how `angular-rails-templates` works : it writes your templates to Angular's `$templateCache`. Angular doesn't force you to cache templates if you want to fetch them from the server every time you need them.

You can stop using `angular-rails-templates` and make your rails app respond to template requests from Angular.